# PHP to display text input content

Tags: php

Im wanting to display the content that a user types into a text box lower down on the page once they've clicked a submit button.

I'm new to PHP and so far i've got this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo 'You entered: ', ($_POST['name']);}?>
```

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's it doing/not doing? is `$_POST['name']` set?

Comment: It's just not displaying anything that was typed into the text input.    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Postcode or Street Name and/or Town..." value="<?php echo $_POST['text'] ?>"  id="address" name="text">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo 'You entered: '.$_POST['name'];}?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  Can you put phpinfo() into your code and look at the "PHP Variables" section to see what is in _POST and _REQUEST ?